# provide option to change avatar in buddypress

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

I have created a custom template for member's profile page. I want to provide change avatar option in that page. So I used the plugin WP User Avatar in my site. I used the short code `[upload avatar]` but using it I get the change avatar option but can't able to browse any Image. Is any other code to change avatar image in buddy press?